# 3.5 inch TFT LCD connection diagram with mega r3

Tags: arduino-mega, lcd

[Forum post](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=257168.0)

I would like to ask if someone has this shield fully working.

My biggest problem is the touch screen that i couldn't manage to make it work.

Here is the code i am using:

```cpp
// ic: ili9327  
#define LCD_RD   A0
#define LCD_WR   A1     
#define LCD_RS   A2        
#define LCD_CS   A3       
#define LCD_REST A4

void Lcd_Writ_Bus(char VH)
{
 unsigned char i,temp,data; 
 data=VH;
 for(i=8;i<=9;i++)
 {
   temp=(data&0x01);
   if(temp)
     digitalWrite(i,HIGH);
   else
     digitalWrite(i,LOW);
   data=data>>1;
 } 
 for(i=2;i<=7;i++)
 {
   temp=(data&0x01);
   if(temp)
     digitalWrite(i,HIGH);
   else
     digitalWrite(i,LOW);
   data=data>>1;
 } 

 digitalWrite(LCD_WR,LOW);
 digitalWrite(LCD_WR,HIGH);
}


void Lcd_Write_Com(char VH)  
{   
 digitalWrite(LCD_RS,LOW);
 Lcd_Writ_Bus(VH);
}

void Lcd_Write_Data(char VH)
{
 digitalWrite(LCD_RS,HIGH);
 Lcd_Writ_Bus(VH);
}

void Lcd_Write_Com_Data(int com,int dat)
{
 Lcd_Write_Com(com);
 Lcd_Write_Data(dat);
}

void Address_set(unsigned int x1,unsigned int y1,unsigned int x2,unsigned int y2)
{
 Lcd_Write_Com(0x2a); // Set_column_address 4 parameters
 Lcd_Write_Data(x1>>8);
 Lcd_Write_Data(x1);
 Lcd_Write_Data(x2>>8);
 Lcd_Write_Data(x2);

 Lcd_Write_Com(0x2b); // Set_page_address 4 parameters
 Lcd_Write_Data(y1>>8);
 Lcd_Write_Data(y1);
 Lcd_Write_Data(y2>>8);
 Lcd_Write_Data(y2);

 Lcd_Write_Com(0x2c); // Write_memory_start 
}

void Lcd_Init(void)
{
 digitalWrite(LCD_REST,HIGH);
 delay(5); 
 digitalWrite(LCD_REST,LOW);
 delay(15);
 digitalWrite(LCD_REST,HIGH);
 delay(15);

 digitalWrite(LCD_CS,HIGH);
 digitalWrite(LCD_WR,HIGH);
 digitalWrite(LCD_CS,LOW);  //CS

 Lcd_Write_Com(0xE9);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x20);

 Lcd_Write_Com(0x11); //Exit Sleep
 delay(100);

 Lcd_Write_Com(0xD1);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x00);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x71);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x19);

 Lcd_Write_Com(0xD0);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x07);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x01);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x08);

 Lcd_Write_Com(0x36);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x48);

 Lcd_Write_Com(0x3A);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x05);

 Lcd_Write_Com(0xC1);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x10);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x10);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x02);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x02);

 Lcd_Write_Com(0xC0); //Set Default Gamma
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x00);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x35);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x00);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x00);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x01);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x02);

 Lcd_Write_Com(0xC5); //Set frame rate
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x04);

 Lcd_Write_Com(0xD2); //power setting
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x01);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x44);

 Lcd_Write_Com(0xC8); //Set Gamma
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x04);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x67);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x35);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x04);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x08);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x06);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x24);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x01);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x37);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x40);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x03);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x10);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x08);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x80);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x00);

 Lcd_Write_Com(0x2A); 
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x00);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x00);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x00);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0xeF);

 Lcd_Write_Com(0x2B); 
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x00);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x00);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x01);
 //  Lcd_Write_Data(0x3F);
 Lcd_Write_Data(0x8F); // on internet

 Lcd_Write_Com(0x29); //display on      

 Lcd_Write_Com(0x2C); //display on 

 digitalWrite(LCD_CS,HIGH);
}

void H_line(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int l, unsigned int c)                   
{ 
 unsigned int i,j;
 Lcd_Write_Com(0x02c); //write_memory_start
 digitalWrite(LCD_RS,HIGH);
 digitalWrite(LCD_CS,LOW);
 l=l+x;
 Address_set(x,y,l,y);
 j=l*2;
 for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
 {
   Lcd_Write_Data(c);
 }
 digitalWrite(LCD_CS,HIGH);   
}

void V_line(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int l, unsigned int c)                   
{ 
 unsigned int i,j;
 Lcd_Write_Com(0x02c); //write_memory_start
 digitalWrite(LCD_RS,HIGH);
 digitalWrite(LCD_CS,LOW);
 l=l+y;
 Address_set(x,y,x,l);
 j=l*2;
 for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
 {
   Lcd_Write_Data(c);
 }
 digitalWrite(LCD_CS,HIGH);   
}

void Rect(unsigned int x,unsigned int y,unsigned int w,unsigned int h,unsigned int c)
{
 H_line(x  , y  , w, c);
 H_line(x  , y+h, w, c);
 V_line(x  , y  , h, c);
 V_line(x+w, y  , h, c);
}

void Rectf(unsigned int x,unsigned int y,unsigned int w,unsigned int h,unsigned int c)
{
 unsigned int i;
 for(i=0;i<h;i++)
 {
   H_line(x  , y  , w, c);
   H_line(x  , y+i, w, c);
 }
}

void LCD_Clear(unsigned int j)                   
{ 
 unsigned int i,m;
 Lcd_Write_Com(0x02c); //write_memory_start
 digitalWrite(LCD_RS,HIGH);
 digitalWrite(LCD_CS,LOW);
 Address_set(0,0,479,399);

 for(i=0;i<480;i++)
   for(m=0;m<400;m++)
   {
     Lcd_Write_Data(j);
   }
 digitalWrite(LCD_CS,HIGH);   
}

void setup()
{
 for(int p=2;p<10;p++)
 {
   pinMode(p,OUTPUT);
 }
 pinMode(A0,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(A1,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(A2,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(A3,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(A4,OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(A0, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(A1, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(A2, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(A3, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(A4, HIGH);
 Lcd_Init();
 LCD_Clear(0x00);
}

void loop()
{  

 for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
 {
   Rect(random(300),random(300),random(300),random(300),random(65535)); // rectangle at x, y, with, hight, color
 }
 LCD_Clear(0x00);
}
```

Here are some pictures:

[1 http://imageshack.com/a/img908/7546/YEctM8.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img908/7546/YEctM8.jpg)
[3 http://imageshack.com/a/img537/5378/GIWz2x.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img537/5378/GIWz2x.jpg)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share some code as well, to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: I was able to make mine work, but these screens are all a little different, please post a link to the exact product you have. You don't have any code to read the touch input.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [MCUFriend kbv library](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/mcufriend_kbv) I used this library for a 3.5 inch display and the driver on it was ILI9486 this library includes all the function and I have tested the touch also this library works good for it also